# PHP Paging in Mysql_Query

Tags: php, mysql, paging

So basically, this is how my paging query looks like at the moment:

```
    $limit = mysql_escape_string($_GET['pagenumber']);
    if (empty($limit)){
    $limit = "1";
    }

    $page = $limit * 10;
    $flim1 = $page / 10;
    $flim = $page - 10;
```

At the end of my query, I have this:

```
    ... LIMIT $flim, $page
```

Which should be from 1, 10 if the pagenumber is 1 and 10, 20 if the page number is 2. It works on the first page perfectly, but when I get to the second, there were 20 results, although when I echoed $flim and $page, they were 10 and 20. I cannot understand why!

I've heard about some double-query for paging. If you know a simple way to do this that is kind of like this one, please post a link. Will my method work?

Answer (score 6):

Please see specification of `LIMIT` there is `LIMIT offset,count`
So in your situation it would be `LIMIT $flim,10`

Full code:

```
$page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['pagenumber']);
if (empty($limit)){
$page = "1";
}
$items_per_page=10;
$offset = ($page-1)*$_items_per_page;
```

Then `LIMIT $offset,$items_per_page`

Additionally you would need count for all items to not get above max page

Comment: also, if you do 1,10 and then 10,20 (or 10,10) you will display item #10 twice

Comment: Well, he made the mistake in his original question.  just needed to point it out.

Comment: For some reason, it makes 0 - 10 on page one,then 10-10, then 20-10?

Comment: For some reason, it makes 0 - 10 on page one,then 10-10, then 20-10?
*edit* Ok, I see it now, offset, count. So I learned something new today too :)!
Thank you so much, great support!